# C++ compile external file SFML

Tags: c++, file, compilation, external

I want to create an app in c++ using the SFML library,in CodeBlocks,in windows.

My goal is to create an app with a nice interface.

The app will generate c++ code from the input of the user.This code will be saved in an external file. The app will then compile this file and use the code in it to do "further tasks".

My problem is that i dont know how to compile that external file. I dont even know if its possible.

If it is tell me some key words that have to do with this topic. If its a complicated process send me some links about this subject. Thank you for helping.

Comment: A compiler compiles files you give to it as external files... If what you want to so is scripting, this is might not be the right approach, consider using a scripting language and not C++. Use it only if you are willing to make your own C++ interpreter. We cannot recommend external resources on answers, neither we provide "how to get started" advice. Consider investigating scripting, then return when you have a more specific question.

Comment: ok. thank you for your time

Comment: On a side note, you could theoretically run compilation subprocess with given code which would compile shared library, then dynamically load it into your running program but it's not feasible. As mentioned, way to go would be creating C++ API for code you want the user access and then create script bindings.

Comment: i didnt quite get the last part? what do you mean when you say "create script bindings"?